# How to hook a conversion for the logical type in Avro deserializer?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am looking for the same information regarding how to hook the conversion. Currently the conversion is always null and I am not able to convert to BigDecimal when the logical type is being used. However, I can see following conversions in the auto-generated stub class. But the object type read by the deserializer is always ByteBuffer and it throws Class Cast Exception.

In the auto-generated stub file (formatted for clarity):

```java
import org.apache.avro.data.Conversions
import org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions
```

```java
protected static final TimeConversions.DateConversion DATE_CONVERSION = new TimeConversions.DateConversion(); 
protected static final TimeConversions.TimeConversion TIME_CONVERSION = new TimeConversions.TimeConversion(); 
protected static final TimeConversions.TimestampConversion TIMESTAMP_CONVERSION = new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion(); 
protected static final Conversions.DecimalConversion DECIMAL_CONVERSION = new Conversions.DecimalConversion();
```

And, it is always NULL for the Conversion in the SpecificDatumReader readField().

`Conversion conversion = ((SpecificRecordBase)).getConversion(f.pos());`

Avro version is 1.8.2 now with Confluent Platform and Registry.

How can the conversion be set in the deserializer?

Comment: Please format your question. Also looking at it you need to import Java classes that you want to use to avoid these long names.

Comment: So, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need a little more context to say exactly what your problem is - you'd not generally call `getConversion()` yourself unless you were writing a serialiser.

The lookup for field -> converter is in the actual generated class; look for this: `private static final org.apache.avro.Conversion<?>[] conversions`

This conversion table seems to only be applicable to serialisation.  When deserialising, you'll need to register the conversions.  I'm not sure why this is the case, but you should be able to fix the issue by adding the following code at startup, which should register the conversions you need.

```java
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new Conversions.DecimalConversion());
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.DateConversion());
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimeConversion());
SpecificData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
```

Depending on the exact codepaths, you may also need to call that code on `GenericData.get()...`

Comment: This did not work. Still getting ClassCastException while deserializing avro messages from kafka.

Comment: Also, This is not true that conversions block is not used while deserialization. If that block is present in avro generated class, avro is able to deserialize the messages whereas not if they are absent.